# In join query to table field have same name means how get the two fields value?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I used a join query to retrieve values from two tables that have the same field name. How can i  get the two fields value?

```
mysql_query("SELECT table1.Name, table2.Name 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Id=table2.userid
ORDER BY table1.Id DECS LIMIT 5")
```

With the above query, I need values from both table1.Name and table2.Name.

Comment: SELECT table1.Name AS table1Name, table2.Name AS table2Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html),

```
SELECT table1.Name as table1Name, table2.Name as table2Name
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Id=table2.userid
ORDER BY table1.Id DECS LIMIT 5
```

**Note**: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Its possible to use three tables in join query? any example:-)

Comment: @nagaking You can use `n` number of joins in your query. If you have any difficulty in joins post as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias:

```
mysql_query("SELECT table1.Name as table1_name, table2.Name as table2_name 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.Id=table2.userid
ORDER BY table1.Id DECS LIMIT 5")
```